# How to indent code on new google appscript interface?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide, indentation, auto-indent

Any guidance on how to indent / turn on auto indent on google appscript with shortcuts would be appreciated!

[image: New Appscript interface]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I am using when indenting manually is <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> on single or multiple lines.

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> for shifting it to the right.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> for shifting it to the left.

After <kbd>{</kbd>, when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it should auto indent itself to the right on the next line.

For Auto Formatting, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to format the whole file.

Or right click in the editor then you can see the option below.

Right Click Options:

[image: right click]

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Fore more information, please see this [Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/) to the new interface.

Answer (score 4):

since it changed and since people might find this post and I need more than 25 characters :

It's <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> now (18/03/2022).
You can obviously see this with the right click in the code.

Comment: ...or use option+shift+F for macos